AndroidのChromeの <input type="file"/> で、カメラ撮影画像が引き渡しされない
問題の再現手順と質問内容
ファイルアップロードを伴うWebアプリを開発しています。
<input type="file" accept="*" onchange=... /> な要素をタップすると、iOSやAndroidでは、フォトライブラリからの選択だけではなく、端末内蔵のカメラで写真を撮影できます。

ここで「カメラ」をタップするとカメラが起動して撮影できます。

ここで「保存」ボタンをタップすると、 <input type="file"/> 要素に値が入り、 onChange イベントが発火することを期待しますが、手元のAndroidのChromeではいずれも発生せず、撮影前の状態に戻ってしまいます。
この問題を回避する方法、つまり、ユーザが「カメラ」をタップして撮影した画像を取得する方法は、何かありますか？
補足：他のファイル選択手段
「カメラ」「ビデオ」「コンテンツマネージャ」の3択の画面において、「ビデオ」を選択して撮影した場合は、期待通り onChange イベントが発火します。「コンテンツマネージャ」も同様に期待通り発火します。「カメラ」だけがおかしいです。
バージョン情報

Chrome 131.0.6778.81 (via Google Play ストア)
Android バージョン : 9（古くて申し訳ない）
端末 : Aquos SH-M05


<input> に capture 属性を付けるとどうでしょうか。

ありがとうございます。 capture="environment" も、 capture="user" も、本件の問題を回避することはできませんでした。それどころか、 capture="user" としてもenvironment側のカメラが起動したので、何か別の問題が潜んでいるのかもしれません。

Pixel 9 + Android 15 だと、capture なしでは撮影不可、capture ありでは問題なく撮影して添付できたので、Aquos か古い Android の問題なのかもしれませんね。

ありがとうございます！どれくらい古かったらダメなのか、を探る旅が必要そうですね…（汗   現時点では、端末起因の可能性は低くて、OSバージョンのどこかで境目（つまりバグ修正）があったのだろう、という可能性が高そうに見えます。
